# d3's fitSize distorted by New Zealand geojson

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to expand this example to include Asia plus Oceania (specifically Australia and New Zealand): https://bl.ocks.org/aholachek/700f930820f2704a957c070173327789

So I replaced the json data in the example with Asia + Oceania from https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/ and trimmed out all the tiny pacific islands.  When I do this I see the entire map skewed to the right (as below).  Whereas by simply removing New Zealand, the map will scale appropriately to the entire canvas.

[image: example of skewed layout]

The relevant area of the code seems to be...

```
 const projection = d3.geoMercator()
   // d3's 'fitSize' magically sizes and positions the map for you
    .fitSize([width, height], data);
```

But I can't find any documentation explaining why fitSize might be getting tripped up on New Zealand (and I need to have New Zealand included in the final visualisation).

Comment: just to add that the problem is that the <path> inside the map's <g> element has a width as large as the entire canvas.

Comment: apologies - I figured out the issue - there were tiny islands (invisible on my laptop screen) associated in the NZ data that were mapped to left of the image.  Closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm adding an answer as it might not be possible to remove features to align the map as intended - say for a map of the Bering Sea or Pacific Rim. Or, you might want to include those tiny NZ islands.*

By default, most D3 projections are centered at 0°N,0°E, with the anti-meridian at 180°W/E. This means any feature split by the anti-meridian will likely end up on two sides of the map. FitSize/fitExtent will then scale and translate the maps so that both sides of the map are visible, likely with a large empty space in between. As you noted, your features bridge the anti-meridian, so fitSize/fitExtent don't work as needed.

Both `projection.fitSize` and `projection.fitExtent` are convenience methods for setting the projection `projection.scale` and `projection.translate`. Both scale and translate modify projected coordinates - all they can do is pan and scale the projected data. Consequently fitSize and fitExtent, nor translate or center, modify the antimeridian.

There are two other useful projection methods: `projection.center()` and `projection.rotate()`. Projection.center translates the map in geographic coordinates. The geographic coordinate specified by .center() and the pixel coordinate specified by .translate() will align in the map. But, `projection.rotate()` will apply a rotation to the map prior to projection, this will shift the anti-meridian.

`projection.rotate` takes an array with two (or three values), the first represents the longitude, the second the latitude. Generally you'll want to leave latitude at 0 - this will change the appearance of the Mercator projection otherwise. Changing the longitude will not alter a Mercator (longitude and projected x values have a linear relationship). In your case, rotating the world 180 degrees would make the prime meridian the anti-meridian, and this would ensure the projection's anti-meridian doesn't intersect your features, which means that fitSize and fitExtent will work as needed and your features will not be on split across two far sides of the map:

```js
var width = 480;
var height = 480;
// feature crossing anti-meridian (180W/E), ensure proper winding direction.
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              150.8203125,
              -28.92163128242129
            ],
            [
              -121.0625,
              -30.145127183376115
            ],

            
            [
              -121.765625,
              -60.586967342258674
            ],
            [
              145.8984375,
              -57.70414723434192
            ],            
            [
              150.8203125,
              -28.92163128242129
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
var projection = d3.geoMercator().rotate([180,0]);
var path = d3.geoPath(projection);

d3.json("https://d3js.org/world-110m.v1.json").then(function(world) {

  // Draw the world.
  let countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
  
  projection.fitSize([width,height],data)
  
  
  let features =  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(countries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width",1);
    
  g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d",path)
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",1);
    
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="480" height="480"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

apologies - I figured out the issue - there were tiny islands (invisible on my laptop screen) associated in the NZ geodata that were mapped to left of the image. Closing